# Add a filter to GTM custom javascript variable array

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

We have a ecommerce system that pushes through a datalayer. Unfortunately, the datalayer includes the 'building blocks' of our products. Resulting in tags that register more information than I would like. I would like to exclude these 'building blocks' through a custom javascript variable. See an example of the datalayer below.

```
    checkout: {
      actionField: {step: 1},
      currencyCode: 'EUR',
      products: [
        {
          name: 'product name',
          id: '40291',
          price: '149,00',
          category: 'Transportation/Other',
          quantity: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'building block 1',
          id: '20231',
          price: '0,00',
          category: 'Transportation/Other',
          quantity: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'building block 2',
          id: '12302',
          price: '0,00',
          category: 'Transportation/Other',
          quantity: 2
```

I've made a CJS variables that makes the products.id, .name, .price and .quantity an array (see below), but I am unable to figure out how to add a filter() that excludes from the array the values where corresponding product.name = "building block 1" && "building block 2".

```
  var products = {{dlv - product}};
  return products.reduce(function(arr, prod) { return arr.concat(prod.id); }, []);
```

Would anybody be able to help me out with this part of the function? Alternatively, I was thinking I might be able to achieve the same with a conditional if() statement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how GTM works, but if you want to filter an array with JS you could use something like this:

```
checkout.products.filter(product => !product.name.includes('building block'))
```

Let me know if this helps or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge. My solution:

**1. Create data layer variable with yours products array**

In my case it was `ecommerce.impressions` data layer variable from productImpression event.

**2. Choose parameters for your filter**

I had:

- variable with products array from step 1 - {{products array}}
- term - only products with this word will be in my filtered array
- custom dimension - 'dimensionXX' - this parameter will be check

**3. Create custom javascript variable with filtered products array**

Paste this function with yours filter parameters

```
function() {
  var items = {{products array}};
  var filtered_items = items.filter(function(filter) {
    return filter.dimensionXX.includes('term');
  }
  );
  return filtered_items;
}
```

**4. Add your custom javascript variable from step 3 to your tag configuration**

Replace your original product array with this custom javascript variable to send filtered product array to GA.